# Laravel filter whereIn by whereNotIn

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am creating a query scope to retrieve some data.

We want to get results where include_ids `[1,2,3]` exist, but filter them if the model is also a part of exclude_ids `[4,5]`.

If a user is subscribed to 2 and 4, they should not be selected. However, a user who is subscribed to 1,2, or 3 and not 4,5 should be selected.

I have been messing around with this for a while and it should look something like this

1. wrap everything in a where statement
2. Load data whereHas relationship to another model exists
3. Get data for the relationship whereIn incl_ids exists
4. How to filter point 3 by excl_ids ?

Maybe we should loop over excl_ids and do not load data when excl_id is true?

```
    public function scopeLoadExcept ($query, $incl_ids, $excl_ids)
    {
        return $query->where(function ($q) use ($incl_ids, $excl_ids) {
            return $q->whereHas('relationship', function ($qq) use ($incl_ids, $excl_ids) {
                return $qq->whereIn('foreign_id', $incl_ids)->where(function ($qqq) use ($excl_ids) {
                    return $qqq->whereNotIn('foreign_id', $excl_ids); // filter this
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: You can use [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to get ids for `whereIn`, that should eliminate the need for the `whereNotIn` clause: `$ids = array_diff($incl_ids, $excl_ids);`

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to filter out related (model) records based on foreign_id which essentially is the id of the parent model. So my question is why not filter the parent record first and then eagerload/lazyload the relations? Or is my understanding not quite right?

Comment: We want to get where incl_ids is true, but do not select any records where excl_ids are true. A user has many subscriptions. Get where subscriptions 1,2,3 are true, but do not select any users that are subscribed to 4,5. Array_diff won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `whereDoesntHave` method

```
public function scopeLoadExcept($query, $incl_ids, $excl_ids)
{
    return $query->where(
        function ($q) use ($incl_ids, $excl_ids) {
            return $q->whereHas(
                'relationship',
                function ($qq) use ($incl_ids, $excl_ids) {
                    return $qq->whereIn('foreign_id', $incl_ids);
                }
            )->whereDoesntHave(
                'relationship',
                function ($qq) use ($incl_ids, $excl_ids) {
                    return $qq->whereIn('foreign_id', $excl_ids);
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

and actually you dont need to use where parameter grouping like below:

```
public function scopeLoadExcept($query, $incl_ids, $excl_ids)
{
    return $query->whereHas(
        'relationship',
        function ($qq) use ($incl_ids) {
            return $qq->whereIn('foreign_id', $incl_ids);
        }
    )->whereDoesntHave(
        'relationship',
        function ($qq) use ($excl_ids) {
            return $qq->whereIn('foreign_id', $excl_ids);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not filter there incl_ids by excl_ids

Comment: it should does, or maybe I misunderstanding , what do you mean for incl_ids by excl_ids?

Comment: It loads the incl_ids fine, but it does not remove excl_ids from the selection. We want to filter incl_ids by excl_ids. If a user is subscribed to 2 and 4, they should not be selected. a user who is subscribed to 1,2,3 but not 4,5 should be selected

Comment: whereDoesntHave will load the model results that don't have the relationship?

Comment: yes, where don't have the relationship and your custom where condition